# WPF - URI relative to currentdirectory?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm converting a Windows Forms VB project to a WPF one (a diary program).
In the Windows Forms version, I displayed images in a picturebox, and I could pass either a full path or a path relative to the My.Computer.Filesystem.CurrentDirectory - the picturebox could work it out.

In the new WPF version, I'd like to do the same.  However, this only works with absolute, not relative paths:

```
Dim TheBitmap As New BitmapImage
TheBitmap.BeginInit()
TheBitmap.UriSource = New Uri(TheURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
TheBitmap.EndInit()
TheImage.Source = TheBitmap
```

Just to confirm, the images aren't resources, they aren't available at design time, so I can't copy them into the solution, and I don't want to locate them in the executable's directory (UAC won't let me without it running as admin anyway I guess)

Everything I've read here and elsewhere about WPF URIs seems to suggest they can only be relative to the executable directory, or the *working directory*, which it seems I can only set in the My Project->Debug page at design time - not what I want.

Can I get WPF to consider a URI relative to the currentdirectory, or do I have to write my own test for it?

Many thanks

Nick

EDIT

By the way, the test I am using in the meantime is:

```
If IO.File.Exists(DatabaseLocation & "\" & TheURL) Then 
 'must be a relative url 
 TheBitmap.UriSource = New Uri(DatabaseLocation & "\" & TheURL,UriKind.Absolute) 
Else 
 'must be an absolute url 
 TheBitmap.UriSource = New Uri(TheURL, UriKind.Absolute) 
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to convert a path that is relative to the current directory to an absolute path by doing the following:

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), relativePath)
```

Then use the resulting path to create an absolute `Uri` that you can use.

Edit: Given the requirement that the incoming path could either be an absolute path *or* a path relative to the current directory, I suggest writing a utility helper method such as the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a file system path, will return an absolute Uri representing that path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">The file system path to turn into a Uri</param>
/// <returns>
/// If the provided path is absolute, returns an absolute Uri representing that path.
/// If the provided path is relative, returns an absolute Uri representing that path relative to the current directory.
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">The provided path value is null</exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">The provided path value is an empty string or invalid file system path</exception>
public static Uri GetAbsoluteUri(string path)
{
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    if (path == string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("Path cannot be an empty string.", "path");

    Uri uri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    {
        return uri;
    }
    if (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Relative, out uri))
    {
        Uri baseUri = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), UriKind.Absolute);
        Uri newUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, uri, out newUri))
        {
            return newUri;
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("The provided path could not be converted to a Uri.", "path");
}
```

You could give any of your paths to this method and get back a an absolute `Uri` that you should be able to use. As written, it will throw an exception if you pass an invalid path, but you can customize it however you want.

EDIT: I forgot this question was VB and not C#. I have attempted to convert the method to VB. Forgive me if something is not exactly right as I do not have experience with VB.

```
Public Shared Function GetAbsoluteUri(path As String) As Uri
    If (path Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("path")
    End If
    If (path = String.Empty) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Path cannot be an empty string.", "path")
    End If

    Dim inUri As Uri = Nothing
    If (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, inUri)) Then
        Return inUri
    End If
    If (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Relative, inUri)) Then
        Dim baseUri As Uri = New Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), UriKind.Absolute)
        Dim newUri As Uri = Nothing
        If (Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, inUri, newUri)) Then
            Return newUri
        End If
    End If

    Throw New ArgumentException("The provided path could not be converted to a Uri.", "path")
End Function
```

Comment: I can easily convert a relative uri - but that won't work if I feed in an absolute one.  Picturebox.LoadAsync() could use either.  I was hoping there was a way to automatically deal with either in WPF too.  In the meantime I wrote my own test.

Comment: Updated my answer with something that might help.

Comment: Thanks Xavier.  I'm actually using VB, but I can work out what your code does.  I think it's basically a more robust version of what I'm using now.  It would have been nice if WPF could do this natively somehow, but I'm learning that along with more flexibility and potential for better organised projects, WPF has a lot of things missing too, compared to Win Forms!

Comment: I completely forgot you were using VB by the time I updated this answer, sorry about that. Hopefully it is helpful anyways, as I am not experienced in VB, and it would take me a while to convert it. There are certainly a number of things missing in WPF that were available in WinForms, but over time as you learn WPF better, you will find that you don't actually need most of them at all. For the times when you do, there is often a simple solution like a small helper method.

Comment: I went ahead and did a VB translation of the method for you and for anyone else who comes along and finds this question. Forgive me if it is not perfect due to my lack of VB knowledge (I did test it at least with a handful of test paths).